# Celery tasks suddenly stop executing, nodes can't find each other

Tags: python, rabbitmq, celery

I have one master server and 6 worker servers (each with a couple workers running on them). All of a sudden, after many months of flawless execution, all of the tasks stopped getting executed, even though there were no code changes. Now, even after rebooting all the servers involved, restarting RabbitMQ, restarting the workers, etc, it appears as though the servers aren't able to find each other, and thus no tasks can be completed.

When I run `celery -A proj inspect active`, the response is `Error: No nodes replied within time constraint.` I'm also able to connect to the broker using Flower, but it lists no workers, even though the workers are running and pointing to the same broker. On the master server, which is in charge of adding tasks, my application now appears to hang indefinitely on `apply_async`.

In my application, I have the broker set to pyamqp, and the backend set to rpc:

`Celery('proj', broker='pyamqp://[master server's IP]', backend='rpc://[master server's IP]')`

I feel like I'm missing something really simple, but I can't figure out what it is.

Comment: Are you able to inspect the RabbitMQ queues or is that also dead? Redis result backend? (Celery is flakey, I’ve switched to [Dramatiq](https://dramatiq.io/) and am much happier.)

Comment: I am able to view the RabbitMQ queues directly using `sudo rabbitmqctl list_queues`. It does list all of the queues, but they're all empty. I'm using rpc as the backend.

Comment: When you write directly to the queue, does Celery pick that up? At least you’d eliminate a communication problem between the queue and Celery. Task data from your app arrives in the queues for workers to pick up, yes?

Comment: I don't believe task data is even arriving in queues for the workers to pick up (how can I test this?), so that means that there's a communication problem between the queue and Celery? How can I debug that?

Comment: I’d [turn on `debug` logging for RabbitMQ](https://www.rabbitmq.com/logging.html#log-levels) and [for Celery](http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/userguide/debugging.html) and then, from a local terminal, spin up a single Celery task and see what comes up…

Comment: Thank you so much for the help. While poking around the RabbitMQ logs, I `cat`ed this file: `/var/log/rabbitmq/rabbit@[server-name].log`, then I scrolled up to the date/time when the issue first started and I found this handy little message there `Disk free space limit now exceeded. Free bytes:999378944 Limit:1000000000` as well as `alarm_handler: {set,{{resource_limit,disk,rabbit@[server-name]},[]}}`. I freed up some space on the drive, and everything started working again, like magic. So, lesson for all you kids out there: things get weird when you're outta space.

Comment: Neat, glad it works again! 

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Navigating to `/var/log/rabbitmq/rabbit@[server-name].log` and scrolling back to when the issue first occurred led me to this message `Disk free space limit now exceeded. Free bytes:999378944 Limit:1000000000`.

Turns out the hard drive was filled to the brim, which was causing all sorts of trouble for RabbitMQ and Celery, it seems. Freeing up space resolved all issues entirely.

Comment: You absolutely must monitor your servers in a production environment. This would have been caught early. Do you have any idea why the space filled up?

Comment: You're right, we should have had a system set up to notify us of this. The space was filled by some growing log files (from our application) which weren't being subject to logrotate.